# Java program to print an x & y coordinate graph and displayed a plotted point

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have to print a 6 by 6 graph and plot a given point. This is an example for x=2 and y=3:

```
 5 . . . . . 
 4 . . . . . 
 3 . x . . . 
 2 . . . . . 
 1 . . . . . 
 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

my code:

```
public static String[][] plotPoint(String[][] plot){
    int x=0, y=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean bool = true;
    while(bool) {
        System.out.println("Enter x coordinate between 0 and 5: ");
        x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter y coordinate between 0 and 5: ");
        y = sc.nextInt();

        if(x>=5||x<0||y>=5||y<0) {
            System.out.println("The coordinates entered exceed the limit.");
        }else {
            x = x-1;
            bool=false;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<6; j++) {
            if(i==x && j==y) {

                plot[x][y]="x";//assigning "x" to coordinates
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return plot;

}

 public static void main(String [] args) {
    int h = 5;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [][] strArr = new String[6][6];
    char c='.';
    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<6; j++) {
            if(j==0||i==5) {
                strArr[i][j] = Integer.toString(h);
                if(i==5)h++;
                else h--;
            }
            else {
                strArr[i][j]= Character.toString(c);
            }
        }
    }

    String[][] nStrArr = new String[6][6];
    nStrArr = plotPoint(strArr);
    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<6; j++) {
            System.out.print(nStrArr[i][j]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Currently it is printing the graph correctly but the point is completely wrong, I think the second if statement within my plotPoint method is incorrect but I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `for` loop is required to mark `x` in the graph. Try this.

```java
public static String[][] plotPoint(String[][] plot) {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean bool = true;
    while (bool) {
        System.out.println("Enter x coordinate between 0 and 5: ");
        x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter y coordinate between 0 and 5: ");
        y = sc.nextInt();

        if (x >= 5 || x < 0 || y >= 5 || y < 0) {
            System.out.println("The coordinates entered exceed the limit.");
        } else {
            y = y + 1;
            bool = false;
        }
    }
    plot[plot.length - y][x] = "x";
    return plot;
}
```